# Cannot connect to Artemis from another pod in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, jms, activemq-artemis

I have two pods one is my ArtemisMQ pod and another is a consumer service.
I have ingress set up so that I can access the console which works, but the issue comes down to when my consumer pod is trying to access port 61616 for connections.

The error I get from my consumer pod

```
Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'PricingSave' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=0, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=AMQ219013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null]
```

My broker config:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>

<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

      <name>Artemis</name>
      
      <broadcast-groups>
        <broadcast-group name="brokerCluster-broadcast">
                <local-bind-address>0.0.0.0</local-bind-address>
                <local-bind-port>10000</local-bind-port>
                <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
                <group-port>9876</group-port>
                <broadcast-period>20</broadcast-period>
                <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
            </broadcast-group>
        </broadcast-groups>

        <discovery-groups>
            <discovery-group name="brokerCluster-discovery">
                <local-bind-port>10000</local-bind-port>
                <local-bind-address>0.0.0.0</local-bind-address>
                <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
                <group-port>9876</group-port>
                <refresh-timeout>10</refresh-timeout>
            </discovery-group>
        </discovery-groups>

      <cluster-connections>
            <cluster-connection name="brokerCluster">
                <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
                <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
                <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
                <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
                <max-hops>1</max-hops>
          <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="brokerCluster-discovery"/>
        </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>

      <connectors>
        <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://PODS_IP:61616</connector>
      </connectors>

      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>

      <!-- this could be ASYNCIO, MAPPED, NIO
           ASYNCIO: Linux Libaio
           MAPPED: mmap files
           NIO: Plain Java Files
       -->
      <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>

      <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>

      <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>

      <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>

      <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>

      <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>

      <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

      <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>

      <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>

      <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>

      <!--
       This value was determined through a calculation.
       Your system could perform 2.84 writes per millisecond
       on the current journal configuration.
       That translates as a sync write every 352000 nanoseconds.

       Note: If you specify 0 the system will perform writes directly to the disk.
             We recommend this to be 0 if you are using journalType=MAPPED and journal-datasync=false.
      -->
      <journal-buffer-timeout>352000</journal-buffer-timeout>


      <!--
        When using ASYNCIO, this will determine the writing queue depth for libaio.
       -->
      <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>
      <!--
        You can verify the network health of a particular NIC by specifying the <network-check-NIC> element.
         <network-check-NIC>theNicName</network-check-NIC>
        -->

      <!--
        Use this to use an HTTP server to validate the network
         <network-check-URL-list>http://www.apache.org</network-check-URL-list> -->

      <!-- <network-check-period>10000</network-check-period> -->
      <!-- <network-check-timeout>1000</network-check-timeout> -->

      <!-- this is a comma separated list, no spaces, just DNS or IPs
           it should accept IPV6

           Warning: Make sure you understand your network topology as this is meant to validate if your network is valid.
                    Using IPs that could eventually disappear or be partially visible may defeat the purpose.
                    You can use a list of multiple IPs, and if any successful ping will make the server OK to continue running -->
      <!-- <network-check-list>10.0.0.1</network-check-list> -->

      <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv4 addresses -->
      <!-- <network-check-ping-command>ping -c 1 -t %d %s</network-check-ping-command> -->

      <!-- use this to customize the ping used for ipv6 addresses -->
      <!-- <network-check-ping6-command>ping6 -c 1 %2$s</network-check-ping6-command> -->




      <!-- how often we are looking for how many bytes are being used on the disk in ms -->
      <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>

      <!-- once the disk hits this limit the system will block, or close the connection in certain protocols
           that won't support flow control. -->
      <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>

      <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
      <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>

      <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>

      <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>

      <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>


      <page-sync-timeout>484000</page-sync-timeout>


            <!-- the system will enter into page mode once you hit this limit.
           This is an estimate in bytes of how much the messages are using in memory

            The system will use half of the available memory (-Xmx) by default for the global-max-size.
            You may specify a different value here if you need to customize it to your needs.

            <global-max-size>100Mb</global-max-size>

      -->

      <acceptors>

         <!-- Acceptor for every supported protocol -->
         <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://PODS_IP:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

         <!-- AMQP Acceptor.  Listens on default AMQP port for AMQP traffic.-->
         <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://PODS_IP:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>

         <!-- STOMP Acceptor. -->
         <acceptor name="stomp">tcp://PODS_IP:61613?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- HornetQ Compatibility Acceptor.  Enables HornetQ Core and STOMP for legacy HornetQ clients. -->
         <acceptor name="hornetq">tcp://PODS_IP:5445?anycastPrefix=jms.queue.;multicastPrefix=jms.topic.;protocols=HORNETQ,STOMP;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

         <!-- MQTT Acceptor -->
         <acceptor name="mqtt">tcp://PODS_IP:1883?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true</acceptor>

      </acceptors>


      <security-settings>
         <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
            <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>

      <address-settings>
         <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
         <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
         <!--default for catch all-->
         <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>dlq</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
      </address-settings>

      <addresses>
         <address name="PricingSave.dlq">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="PricingSave.dlq"/>
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="PricingSave">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="PricingSave"/>
            </anycast>
         </address>

         <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
         </address>

      </addresses>

      <!-- Uncomment the following if you want to use the Standard LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin pluging to log in events
      <broker-plugins>
         <broker-plugin class-name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl.LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin">
            <property key="LOG_ALL_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_CONNECTION_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_SESSION_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_CONSUMER_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_DELIVERING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_SENDING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_INTERNAL_EVENTS" value="true"/>
         </broker-plugin>
      </broker-plugins>
      -->

   </core>
</configuration>
```

My Artemis Service config:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    name: amq
  name: amq
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    app: amq
  ports:
    - name: web
      port: 8161
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8161
    - name: stomp
      port: 61613
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 61613
    - name: mqtt
      port: 1883
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 1883
    - name: openwire
      port: 61616
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 61616
    - name: jmx
      port: 9404
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9404
    - name: hornetq
      port: 5445
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 5445
    - name: amqp
      port: 5672
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 5672
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

My Artemis deployment Config:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    name: amq
  name: amq
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: amq
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        linkerd.io/inject: enabled
      labels:
        app: amq
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: REPOSITORY/IMAGE
        name: amq
        env:
          - name: KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          - name: CONTAINER_CORE_LIMIT
            valueFrom:
              resourceFieldRef:
                resource: limits.cpu
          - name: CONTAINER_MAX_MEMORY
            valueFrom:
              resourceFieldRef:
                resource: limits.memory
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8161
          name: web
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 61613
          name: stomp
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 1883
          name: mqtt
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 61616
          name: openwire
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9404
          name: jmx
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 5445
          name: hornetq
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 5672
          name: amqp
          protocol: TCP
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 200m
            memory: 512Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 400m
            memory: 1012Mi
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
            add:
              - NET_ADMIN
              - NET_RAW
      restartPolicy: Always
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: my-registry...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more testing locally on minikube which worked, I rebuilt my cluster and redeployed.
I decided not to deploy nor reconfigure linkerd on this new cluster and everything is now working fine.

So the issue I've had must have been done to some proxy settings to do with linkerd. I'll follow this post up when I find a solution to get connections through linkerd.

Answer (score 1):

Using `0.0.0.0` for a connector is not valid. In fact, there should be a `WARN` level message in the log about it. Your cluster will not form properly with such a configuration. You need to use a hostname or IP address that other hosts can use to reach the broker that broadcasts it. That's the whole point of the `broadcast-group` - to tell other brokers who may be listening how they can connect to it.

Comment: Sorry was missing from the config I pasted - added it in

Comment: Thanks. So I've changed it to the hostname of 'amq' and I get `AMQ224000: Failure in initialisation: java.lang.IllegalStateException: AMQ229230: Failed to bind acceptor artemis to amq:61616`

I would use the ClusterIP that gets assigned but that changes on each deployment.

Comment: An arbitrary name like `amq` won't work since it won't be valid for the machine (as you've found). You'll need to find a way to identify the proper hostname or IP address and pass it into the `broker.xml`. You could potentially set a system property on the command-line when starting the broker and then reference that in `broker.xml` using the `${propertyName}` syntax.

Comment: So I've come up with a way to inject it into the broker.xml using xmlstarlet during the entrypoint.sh execution. However getting, `Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'PricingSave' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=3, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is ActiveMQConnectionTimedOutException[errorType=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT message=AMQ219013: Timed out waiting to receive cluster topology. Group:null]`
on the connecting POD. The netty connector is now on port 61610. Do I connect through this port or to 61616?

Comment: It's not clear why you configured a new `acceptor` for port `61610` and pointed your `connector` at it, especially since this port doesn't appear to be mapped in your service or deployment config. I recommend you just use port `61616`. There's not much (if any) benefit in defining a new `acceptor` for clustering.

Comment: I did so as I was getting: `AMQ224000: Failure in initialisation: java.lang.IllegalStateException: AMQ229230: Failed to bind acceptor netty-connector to POD_IP:61616`

Comment: The error message indicates you're attempting to bind an `acceptor` named `netty-connector` to `POD_IP:61616`. You already have an `acceptor` bound to `POD_IP:61616` (i.e. the `acceptor` named `artemis`). You don't need to configure a new `acceptor`. Just point your `connector` to `POD_IP:61616`.

Comment: Thanks, changed and amq is running fine. But still getting the `Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination` error on my connecting Pod. Going through `tcp://AMQ_POD_ID:61616`

Comment: `Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination` is the error message from Spring. Is there a specific error from the Artemis JMS client implementation?

Comment: It is from my Spring app, it produces this message 5 times then kills the pod due to timeout. Nothing shows up in the Artemis Pod logging, nor do I see any consumer connect during the time my Spring app is attempting to connect.

Comment: In your previous comments the "refresh" error messages also had a "Cause:" which was a specific error from the Artemis JMS client. Is that now gone? If so, I don't really have enough information to help.

Comment: BTW, if you just run the brokers on your local machine (e.g. binding to different loop-back interfaces) does everything work? I'd start there. Once you confirm that everything works locally then you can start containerizing it.

Comment: So Artemis looks to be all fine now and is running on the cluster. Surprisingly enough all works fine locally as docker containers and when running on minikube.
What information would you need, happy to link you repos and provide more details on configuration.